# How to set NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey？

Tags: ios, objective-c, stream

I need to read the file at the specified location through the file location returned by the server. I tried to use `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey` to set the starting position of the file read, but the code display settings failed.

**Code:**

```
NSInputStream *oStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:self.fileData];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:self.serverLength];
BOOL success = [oStream setProperty:number forKey:NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey];
oStream.delegate = self;
[oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[oStream open];
```

[Code running screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NScCg.png)

I want to know why the setting fails and how to set `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `NSStream` states

> NSStream instances that are not file-based are non-seekable, one-way
>   streams

There may be two possible solutions to this:

- create the input stream directly from a file(path) (see documentation for `inputStreamWithFileAtPath:` / `inputStreamWithURL:`) and set `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey`, or
- create the input stream with a subrange of filedata: `[self.filedata subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange( self.serverLength, self.filedata.length - self.serverLength)]`

Which one is more appropriate depends on where filedata actually gets its data from.

Comment: Yes, `inputStreamWithFileAtPath` solved my problem.